# Выделить обращение к участнику

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

У меня предложение, отмечать обращение к участнику цветной ссылкой на профиль, для удобочитаемости, когда сообщение адресовано/задано конкретному участнику, подчеркиваю и то, что в комментариях, очень трудно уловить когда обращаются к кому-либо, сейчас это выглядит вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, функция: `@<Имя участника>` остается монотонным, и не подчеркивает само обращение к участнику обсуждения. Я же предлагаю сделать чтобы данная функция работала вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно из изображения, все понятно, удобочитаемо, а также можно заглянуть на страничку участника и посмотреть его профиль, думаю много времени это не займет, и сам функционал не такой уж и громоздкий.

Answer (score 3):

А. Не вижу в этом нововведении пользы. Когда и зачем нужно акцентироваться на профиле участника? В приведенном примере, какой практический смысл в переходе на страницу участника?

Б. Ссылки на профиль обычно и так присутствуют вокруг, в самом вопросе и/или предыдущих комментариях.

В. Когда идет обращение к участнику в комментариях, куда полезнее было бы подсвечивать, как в чате, предыдущее сообщение от этого участника, чтобы было понятно на какой комментарий дается ответ/отзыв. НО, отсутствие этого вероятно намеренное, чтобы не поощрять общение в комментариях - для этого есть чат.

Comment: Чтобы лучше видеть структуру диалога в комментариях, используйте userscript Threading Comments.